# Is there a way to tell if we're being called inside a constructor?

Tags: c++

I want to make a nonstatic method that only constructors of the same instance of the class (or one of its subclasses) may call.  Is there an elegant way to do this, short of a key-oriented access protection pattern?

```
class MyClass
{
   public:
     void foo()
     {
        assert(foo was called from the constructor); //how?!
        if (some condition or other)
            throw ExceptionThatOnlyClientsThatConstructTheObjectCanHandle();  //hence my requirement
     }
};

class MySubClass : public MyClass
{
  public:
     MySubClass() 
     { 
       blah(); //correct use of foo() through blah()
       foo(); //correct use of foo() directly
     } 
     void blah() { foo(); } //correctness depends on who called blah()
};

int main()
{
   MySubClass m;
   m.foo(); // incorrect use of foo()
   m.blah(); // incorrect use of foo() through blah()
   return 0;
}
```

Edit: see my comments below, but I think this is either a special case of (1) transitive key-oriented access control or (2) making sure exceptions are handled.  Seeing it like that, the constructor thing is a red herring.

Comment: First, make it protected not public. That won't help determining if a constructor called it, but at least users of the class won't have access to it. As to the core of your question, I believe the best is to rely on programmers' good will.

Comment: Are you aware of base class initializers and delegating constructors? They may serve for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Well since `blah` calls `foo`, the only one allowed to see the function `blah` should be the class, hence `blah` should be private. Can't you move the code of `foo` into the constructor of `MyClass`?

Comment: Interesting. Are you trying to make sure your chain of calls is always started by a constructor ? Or are you ok with depth 2 check ? (ctor->blah()->foo() ) ? Is C++ 11 allowed ?

Comment: You're all right, I should have made it `protected` (hastily written question, sorry!).  @AlexK I want to make sure it always starts with the constructor.  I'm not using C++11 but I'm sure if that does permit a solution then that would be educational for all :)  Looking at the problem with a fresh head I think I'll take syam's suggestion and stick to good will though.

Comment: See edit & upcoming reply to Cole

Comment: Talking of goodwill, there is another solution here: rename `foo()` to  `constructor_foo()` to avoid any confusion

Comment: Now might be a good time to accept an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Have your points, Cole, but not for the bit about "just putting the code there" :-)  Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is not possible without some other variable telling you. The best thing you can do is make the methods `private` so only your class can call it. Then make sure that only the constructor calls it. Other than that, it you only want the constructor calling it, have you tried *not using a function and just putting the code there*?

Comment: In practice the function is called multiple times with different arguments.  Your italicised comment does make me think we could bring it in/out of scope with `#define`/`#undef` though.